# Can't get my menu to work with "StickyPanel"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I'm kinda new to creating websites, so bear with me.

I just started a new project and I wanted a menu that follows when you scroll, and then stops when it reaches the top of the page. I found a really cool JavaScript plugin called `"StickyPanel"` ( https://code.google.com/p/sticky-panel/ ), but it won't cooperate. Apparently there are no instructions and I can't find any useful info else where.

The code is very simple:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.stickyPanel.min.js"></script>

<!-----Sticky Panel------>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {

            var stickyPanelOptions = {
                afterDetachCSSClass: "",
                savePanelSpace: true
            };
            $("header").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".nav-button").click(function () {
            $(".nav-button,.menu").toggleClass("open");
            });    
        });
    </script>

<!-----Sticky Panel------>
```

Then I made a `div` class called "header" and then styled the header-menu. I can't get the JavaScript to do anything with my header. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
        $("header").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);
```

You ask Jquery for the elemet header 
You need to ask jquery the class header =>

```
        $(".header").stickyPanel(stickyPanelOptions);
```

Read about slectors its usefull!

```
        <header> is a html5 element, support by almost all browser but dont forget display: block in css!
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick anwser. I've tried your suggestion, but that doesn't work either : ( I found a website who has the same javascript plugin maybe that could help. Is it allowed to link to his website?

Comment: ow, well you changed header to .header as selector ? give me a second

Comment: I've tried the last thing you said about the <header> element and now when the menu reachers the top, it resets to it's deffault position. Really wierd, but at least the menu is linked to the javascript now : )

Comment: I want my menu like on this website. Where it is on the middel of the page in the beginnig and then follow until it reachers the top. http://manoscrafted.com/.

Answer (score 0):

select your div using `$(".header")` Instead of `$("header")`

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to it if you don't want to use this plugin. found this code somewhere on internet. it uses `position:fixed` css style, simple js

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () { 
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    var e = $("#StickyPanel"); 
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 602 || window.pageYOffset >= 602) { 
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "6.0") 
    { 
    e.css("top", document.documentElement.scrollTop + 15 + "px") } 
    else { 
    e.css({ position: "fixed", top: "1%" }) } } 
    else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 602 || window.pageYOffset < 602) 
    {            
     e.css({ position: "absolute", top: "91%" }) } }) }
     </script>
```

**css**

```
#search
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 91%;
 }
```

just change the values

> 602

according to your needs

Hope it helps.

This is what you are asking for:
**JSFIDDLE**
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hx33N/)

Comment: @user2157183 u can check the demo